# Session login script doesn't pass form variable values to $_POST?

Tags: php, html

Keep getting *Error: admin login* when logging in as admin(admin form). Customers **don't** yet have a table(the db_table_customers).

**Edit**: Using Wamp it gives me this

---

```
( ! ) Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\dev6\login.php on line 36
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0003  692264  {main}( )   ..\login.php:0
2   0.0121  710400  mysqli_num_rows ( ) ..\login.php:36
```

Line 36 is `$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);`

Also, var_dump()ing $result and $row respectively prints the following in the web browser:

> boolean false
>
> null

---

Which should mean that the login.php can't match the provided login for admin in my db_table_admins table. But I'm providing the correct login information for admin. Checked multiple times.

**Form**

```
<form name="admin_login" method="POST" action="login.php">
        <h3>Admin:</h3>
        Username: <input type="text" id="username" name="admin_login[username]"><br>
        Password: <input type="password" id="password" name="admin_login[password]"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="admin_submit" value="Login">
</form> 

<form name="customer_login" method="POST" action="login.php">
        <h3>Customer:</h3>
        Username: <input type="text" id="username" name="customer_login[username]"><br>
        Password: <input type="password" id="password" name="customer_login[password]"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="customer_submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

**Login.php**

```
<?php

    require('connection.inc.php');

    $username = null;
    $password = null;
    $administrator = false;
    $result = null;

    $link = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database) or die("Can't connect");

    if(isset($_POST['admin_submit'])){
            $administrator = true;
            $username = $_POST['admin_login']['username'];
            $passname = $_POST['admin_login']['password'];
    }else{
            $username = $_POST['customer_login']['username'];
            $passname = $_POST['customer_login']['password'];
    }

    if($administrator){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $db_table_admins WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($rows == 1){
            $_SESSION['admin'] = true;
            header("location:login_success.php");
        }else{
            echo "Error: admin login";
        }
    }else{
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $db_table_customers WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($rows == 1){
            $_SESSION['admin'] = false;
            header("location:login_success.php");
        }else{
            echo "Error: customer login";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You're vulnerable to SQL injection. Please read up on prepared statements and bound variables.

Comment: And don't store passwords in plain text. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: @Quentin
I've omitted the part of the code that prevent SQL injection.

Comment: @Quentin
I'm aware of that. I was going to implement the password encryption after this anyways.

Comment: "I've omitted the part of the code that prevent SQL injection." -- really? so this is not even your code? then what are we trying to fix here?

Comment: Just a thought here. Instead of having two forms you could have one form with a username and password box followed by a radio button group for either `admin` or `customer`. This would allow you to eliminate the entire second form. Just a thought...Sorry I know this doesn't answer your question but it's a little optimization that may help you out.

Comment: @War10ck
No, that's actually a very good idea. I'll highly consider it.

Comment: @Jack
This is my code...

Comment: @Gentoo You sure about that because `<input name="admin_submit" ..>` but `if ($_POST['admin_login']) ...` -- obviously that can't work.

Comment: @Jack
I thought this way was correct.
I tried changing that just now like jeroen pointed out. Still didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure there is only one record for the admin in the database? You're only checking if `$rows == 1`. It would help to debug this by outputting `$rows` and possibly `$result` to get a better idea of what's going on here, then reporting back to us.

Comment: Hmm no, I read too fast; didn't realize you named the textboxes as `"admin_login[xxx]"`.

Comment: @Joey
Yes, 1 admin record. $row and $result appear to be empty(int(0) and null)

Answer (score 0):

You have `$administrator = true;` but you test `if($admin){`

Comment: That was a post typo. Problem still persists.

Comment: @Gentoo Don't retype code from your existing code unless it's to obfuscate passwords and other sensitive info.

Answer (score 0):

Your admin login button is called `admin_submit`:

```
 <input type="submit" name="admin_submit" value="Login">
```

but in your code you check for `admin_login`:

```
if($_POST['admin_login']){
```

You need to check for (and change to...) `admin_submit` as `admin_login` is already used for your text fields

**Edit:** As pointed out, you have an sql injection problem. That means that for example a `'` character in your `$_POST` will break your query.

Apart from that, you seem to be using variables for your table names; where do these come from / are they set?

Comment: I've omitted the SQL injection prevention piece due to clarity of the code snippet. So, that should be fine and taken care of. 
The variables for my table names are set in a separate include file(the connection.inc.php) and are correct. I've checked.